# Second order 1D equation with integral boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, difference-equations

Is it possible to solve below equation in Mathematica in range $0<x<r$?

$f''[x] + \frac{2f'[x]}{x} = -A e^{-B f[x]}$

$ f'[x]|_{x=r}=-\alpha\:\:\:\:\:$ and $\:\:\:\int_0^r f(x) x^2 dx= \gamma$

$A$,$B$,$\alpha$,$\gamma$ and $r$ are real known parameters.

I think NDSolve should help but I don't know how to account for integral boundary condition. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of  TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.I would be good if you can add the missing parameters, otherwise people will most likely not want to try.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will do that @MariuszIwaniuk

Answer (score 6):

**Approximate solution by Series with 1 term.**

Linearizing  function `Exp[-B f[x]]` with series in point `r/2`:

```
linear = (Series[-A*Exp[x], {x, r/2, 1}] // Normal) /. x -> -B f[x]
sol = f[x] /. DSolve[{f'[r] == -α, f''[x] + 2*f'[x]/x == linear}, f[x],x][[1]]
```

Integral boundary condition:

```
sol1 = Integrate[sol*x^2, {x, 0, r}] == γ
```

Finding const `C[1]`:

```
sol2 = Solve[sol1, C[1]]
```

Symbolic solution `f[x]` :

```
solution = sol /. sol2[[1]] // Simplify

(* (E^(-((3 r)/4) - 5 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r - 
Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)
  x) (-6 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r + 6 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r)
   r (-E^(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) (r + x)) (-2 + r) x - 
    B r^2 \[Alpha] + 
    2 B E^(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r) r^2 \[Alpha] + 
    B E^(2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) x) r^2 \[Alpha]) + 
 3 E^((3/4 + 5 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)) r) (-1 + E^(
    Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)
      r)) (-E^(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) x) (-2 + r) x - 
    E^(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) (r + x)) (-2 + r) x + 
    2 B E^(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r) r^2 \[Alpha] + 
    2 B E^(2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) x) r^2 \[Alpha]) - 
 2 A^(3/2) B^(3/2) E^((3/2 + 7 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)) r)
   r (-2 r^3 + r^4 + 6 B \[Gamma]) + 
 A^2 B^2 E^((7/4 + 5 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)) r) (E^(
    2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r) + E^(
    2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) x)) r^2 (-2 r^3 + r^4 + 
    6 B \[Gamma]) + 
 A B E^((5 r)/4 + 
   5 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)
     r) (-3 E^(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) x) (-2 + r) r^2 x - 
    3 E^(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) (2 r + x)) (-2 + r) r^2 x + 
    E^(2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)
       x) (2 r^3 + r^4 (-1 + 6 B \[Alpha]) - 6 B \[Gamma]) + 
    E^(2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4)
       r) (-2 r^3 + r^4 (1 + 6 B \[Alpha]) + 
       6 B \[Gamma]))))/(6 B (-1 + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r) (1 -
  E^(2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r) + Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r + 
 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4 + 2 Sqrt[A] Sqrt[B] E^(r/4) r) r) x)*)

 r = 1; (* A random values *)
 A = 1;
 B = 1;
 α = 1;
 γ = 1;
 Plot[solution, {x, 0, r}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {20, 2}}]
```

[image]

**EDIT: 06.07.2018**

**Numeric solution:**

I assume a dummy boundary condition like `f[1] == c` then I only need to find `c` by `FindRoot`.

```
r = 1;(*Assume values*)
A = 1;
B = 1;
\[Alpha] = 1;
\[Gamma] = 1;

sol3[c_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{f'[r] == -\[Alpha], f[1] == c, 
f''[x] + 2*f'[x]/x == -A*Exp[-B*f[x]]}, f, {x, 1/10000, 1}]

INT[c_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(f[x] /. sol3[c])*x^2, {x, 0, r}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];

search = c /. FindRoot[INT[c] == \[Gamma], {c, 1, 10}, Method -> "Secant"]
(* c is: 2.5066 *)
```

Check boundary condition `f'[1] == -1` and `Integrate[f[x]*x^2, {x, 0, 1}] == 1`  :

```
D[(f[x] /. sol3[search]), x] /. x -> 1
(* -1. *)(* OK *)
NIntegrate[(f[x] /. sol3[search])*x^2, {x, 0, r}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
(* 1. *)(* OK *)

Plot[{solution, Evaluate[f[x] /. sol3[search]]}, {x, 1/10000, r}, 
PlotLegends -> {"symbolic only with 1 term", "numeric"}]
```

[image]

It seems 1-term not really enough to  good approximate solution,need more terms.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand why it is not accurate.

Comment: @HolgerMate. I took only 1 term $\exp (x)\approx 1+x$

Comment: @HolgerMate .I edited my answer.